# Are there any compilers/transpilers that have dead-code elimination?

Tags: javascript

Are there any languages with "compilers" that produce JavaScript, are actively maintained, and have dead-code elimination?

Answer (score 1):

- PureScript: [www.purescript.org](http://www.purescript.org)
- Javascript++: https://www.onux.com/jspp/
- Nim: https://nim-lang.org/docs/backends.html 
  (but it's still very experimental when it comes to JavaScript.)

Comment: Please add at least the license (or price) of each, thanks! :-)

Comment: Please also read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality cheers!